# Voted best answer revoked?

Tags: support, reputation

I was voted the best answer on a post - and I was the only one posting. The question was then downvoted and I no longer have the reputation from being the best answer. Is this related? Or did the OP decide he didn't like my answer. Thanks.

Comment: What question? I don't see any answer that was accepted, but I also see no downvotes.

Comment: Not this question @JoeTaxpayer. It was on the Personal Finance and Money webpage. Not sure if this is the appropriate area to ask about this, but I didn't want to do it there.

Comment: That's where I looked. I looked at your profile to see your answers. I didn't see any DV on any answer.

Comment: Well, I did have an accepted answer, and I swear I'm not crazy. I can't remember exactly which question. it may have dealt with taxes from an alien, but I could be wrong. Either way, thanks for the help.

Comment: I have had down votes on answers though, because I've received -2 points before..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The green checkmark is solely assigned by the original question poster, and has no relation to voting - either on that answer, on the question, or anywhere else.  The original poster may at any time assign, change, or revoke the green checkmark at his/her discretion.